# how to set log level to error for engine info

Tags: log4j, hsqldb

```
11:11:57,792 [ INFO] [ENGINE:763] [main] - open start

11:11:57,801 [ INFO] [ENGINE:763] [main] - open end

11:11:57,812 [ INFO] [ENGINE:763] [main] - checkpointClose start

11:11:57,891 [ INFO] [ENGINE:763] [main] - dataFileCache commit start

11:11:57,979 [ INFO] [ENGINE:763] [main] - checkpointClose end
```

i want to SET the level ERROR insttead of INFO so how can i do this.
The below one also not working

```
<logger name="org.hsqldb">
<level value="ERROR" />
<appender-ref ref="orghsqldb"/>
```

it takes default as root log setting rather any logger or category setting

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you setup your log4j properties.

If you're using a properties file, you can write this before the appenders (example):
`log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, stdout, stderr, R`
And later on:
`log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=ERROR`

Also, you can use [`Logger`'s setLevel method](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html#setLevel%28org.apache.log4j.Level%29) inside your code (in the initialization).